# MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS value keeps on changing in the reducer class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to use the MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS counter in the reducer class to calculate the percentage of words in the sample wordcount program.

Here is the code for the `setup()` method in the reducer:

```
public static class IntSumReducer extends  
    Reducer<Text,FloatWritable,Text,FloatWritable> {  
    private FloatWritable result = new FloatWritable();  
    private long total = 0;  

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException , InterruptedException{  
        total = context.getCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter",  "MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS").getValue();
        System.out.println("total : " + total);
    }
```

This is the output of the print statement in the last line:

total : 1131
total : 487
total : 421
total : 333
total : 101
total : 101
total : l95
total : l85
total : 0

I don't understand:

1. Why the `setup()` method is getting called multiple times? According to the definition, it should get called only once at the start of the task.
2. Why does the value of 'MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS' keeps on changing? Shouldn't it be one unique value? (The total output of all the mappers combined)?

I dont think the reducers start before all the mappers have finished executing . Why isn't the 'MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS' value a constant?

Comment: I don't think the reducers start before all the mappers have finished their jobs . Only the shuffling of records start.

Comment: How many reducers u have?

Answer (score 0):

"Any reduce function call should be after all the mappers have done
their work".

is strictly true only if speculative execution is explicitly turned off.
Otherwise there is a chance that some reduce tasks can actually start before all the maps are complete.

For that, please check the link,

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/201002.mbox/%3C5f6b7e1002011502u774934f9x5800590f264a933a@mail.gmail.com%3E

1) Regarding setup() method calling, it might happen that multiple reducers are launched for your job and for each reducer, setup method is called.
Please check,

[setup and cleanup methods of Mapper/Reducer in Hadoop MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889152/setup-and-cleanup-methods-of-mapper-reducer-in-hadoop-mapreduce)

2) MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS keeps changing because as per Hadoop-Definative guide book,

MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS:
"The number of map output records   produced    by  all the maps    in  the job.
Incremented every   time    the collect()   method  is  called  on  a   map’s OutputCollector".

It might happen that mappers are running and at the same time reducer's setup() method is called, hence the MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS is changing for each call.

I hope this answer helps.