# Why is My MapReduce job Not Counting Correctly?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently writing a MapReduce task to parse through a dataset and list movies that have 500+ 5-star ratings.

To do this, I already have a mapreduce jobs that filter action movies from a list of movies, and one that filters 5-star reviews for movies.  The inputs to this new job, and to each mapper, is a list of movieIDS.

The input to the first mapper is a list of MovieIDS that are applicable to be counted FOR.  And the input to the second mapper is a movieID that has gotten a single 5-star review.

My task is then to join these in the reducer, by counting the number of 5-star reviews a particular movie (key) has gotten, seeing if it has gotten a total of 500 reviews, and then seeing if that particular movie has been filtered in the list of applicable movies.

My problem, however, is that the HashMap data structure I'm using to count the number of 5-star reviews for a particular movie ID is only ever initialized to one.

Here is the code:

```
public class JoinRatings extends Configured implements Tool {
public static class TokenizerMapperA extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text node1;
    private Text node2 = new Text("1");

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //Write movie ID and int writeable 1
        node1 = new Text(value.toString());
        context.write(node1, node2);
    }
}
public static class TokenizerMapperB extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text node1;
    private Text node2 = new Text("2");

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        node1 = new Text(value.toString());
        context.write(node1, node2);
    }
}

public static class CountReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, NullWritable>{
    private Text node1;
    private Set<String> distinctNodes;
    Map<String, Integer> map;
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private final static IntWritable two = new IntWritable(2);

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) {
        distinctNodes = new HashSet<String>(); 
        map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
     }

     @Override
     protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) {
        //Add all action movie IDs to unique set distinctNodes
        String keyString = key.toString().strip();
        String valueString = "NULL";
        int counter = 0

            for (Text text : values) {
                String value = text.toString().strip();

                    // try {
                    //  Text testText = new Text(value);
                    //  context.write(testText, NullWritable.get());
                    // } catch (IOException e) {
                    //  e.printStackTrace();
                    // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //  e.printStackTrace();
                    // }

                if (value.equals("1")) {
                    distinctNodes.add(keyString);
                }
                else if (value.equals("2")) {
                    if (map.containsKey(keyString)) {
                        map.put(keyString, map.get(keyString) + 1);
                    } else {
                        map.put(keyString, 1);
                    }
                }
            }


    
     }

     @Override
     protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String numOfDistinctNodes = Integer.toString(distinctNodes.size());
        context.write(new Text(numOfDistinctNodes), NullWritable.get());
        String sizeOfMap = Integer.toString(map.size());
        context.write(new Text(sizeOfMap), NullWritable.get());


        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapElement : map.entrySet()) {
                String test = Integer.toString(mapElement.getValue());
                context.write(new Text(test), NullWritable.get());
        }

        for (String s: distinct nodes) {
            if (map.containsKey(s)) {
                if (map.get(s) >= 500) {
                    node1 = new Text(s);
                    context.write(node1, NullWritable.get());
                }
            }
        }
        
        //Order movieID by ascending

        //Write all movie IDs with 500+ 5-star reviews (to context)
     }
}
```

As you can see I am using a Text value from the mappers to distinguish between which data-structure the reducer should be adding to.  This seems to work well for Text "1", which is adding applicable movies the 5 star ratings can count towards to a HashSet, but my HashMap is not counting the number of 5 star reviews for a particular key/MovieID, only ever initializing values to 1.

My inclination is that I'm using MapReduce incorrectly, and that the reducer is getting only a single input of {MovieID, 2}, instead of {MovieID, 2, 2, 2, 2}.

Comment: You seem to be missing your Driver class and sample of your input data. Refer [mcve]

Comment: May be move to Spark and make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Reducers are distributed, so cannot be used to store state between each instance, such as a Map. More particularly, notice that `key` parameter is one instance - you get one Reducer class instance per unique key; not all keys are passed through that one instance function.

You can use Hadoop `DistributedCache` or `Counter` for maintaining some state across tasks, but you should already have all values from the same ID in a single `Iterable<Text>` object. E.g. all reviews (with star count) by-id. Therefore, filter by `value.getStars() == 5`. (Look into defining a Writable `Movie` class, rather than using `Text`), then define a simple counter, e.g.

```
int fiveStarCount = 0;
for (Text t : values) {
  // todo: get stars
  fiveStarCount += parseStars(t) == 5 ? 1 : 0;
}
if (fiveStarCount >= 500) {
  context.write(movieId, NullWritable.get());  // assuming you only care about the movie id
}
```

Then, there is nothing to sort here... You need a second MapReduce job to read that output, then you write `(null,id)` tuples, then the reducer can sort the value by dumping all data into something like `TreeSet` object and writing back to the context.

---

If you really need to filter, join, and sort, I'd recommend Hive or Spark over pure Mapreduce

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer thanks so much for your answer!  You cleared up a lot of how MapReduce was working for me and got it all implemented now.   However, in my testing it would appear that by only having a single reducer you are able to save intermittent values between keys.  This appears to be consistent with KaiZhao's answer here [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889152/setup-and-cleanup-methods-of-mapper-reducer-in-hadoop-mapreduce).  Might I be misinterpreting something?

Comment: You should only force all data to one reducer if you have one key (e.g. null). Otherwise, there really is no point to using mapreduce as you're not distributing your dataset